# Carrierwave is not handling file upload when AR backed object is updated

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave

Can the update action in rails handle file uploads with Carrierwave? After completing the action I cannot find a record of the 'uploaded' image any where. In rails console, I call, user.small_cover, and the following is returned which does not look satisfactory: #, @mounted_as=:small_cover>

My update action is fairly large so I will only show the important slice

```
...
elsif a_nonprofit_staff_member_updates_profile?(organization)
  @user.update_columns(user_params)
  flash[:notice] = "You have updated your profile successfully."
  redirect_to user_path(@user.id)
...
def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, 
      :organization_id, :bio, :skills, :interests, :position, :user_group, :contact_reason,
      small_cover: [:original_filename] )
end
```

I tried just using, :small_cover, as the attribute but got an error, no Name method for Nil object, which was very strange to me seeing as that the object was not nil and I was not calling a, name, method. Am I packaging the submitted parameters correctly?

How does one upload a file successfully using carrierwave when the action is updating and not creating an AR backed object in rails? Am I handling the parameters incorrectly

UPDATE:
Here is the relevant code for my user model and my uploader

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_secure_password validations: false
  belongs_to :organization
  has_one :administrated_organization, foreign_key: 'user_id', class_name: 'Organization'
  has_many :sent_messages, class_name: 'PrivateMessage', foreign_key: 'sender_id'
  has_many :received_messages, -> {order('created_at DESC')}, class_name: 'PrivateMessage', foreign_key: 'recipient_id'

  has_many :administrated_projects, through: :administrated_organization, source: :projects

  has_many :volunteer_requests,  class_name: 'VolunteerApplication', foreign_key: 'administrator_id'
  has_many :projects, through: :volunteer_applications, source: :administrator
  has_many :delegated_projects, class_name: "Contract", foreign_key: 'contractor_id'
  has_many :projects, through: :contracts, source: :contractor

  has_many :requests_to_volunteer, class_name: 'VolunteerApplication', foreign_key: 'applicant_id'
  has_many :projects, through: :volunteer_applications, source: :applicant
  has_many :assignments, class_name: "Contract", foreign_key: 'volunteer_id'
  has_many :projects, through: :contracts, source: :volunteer

  has_many :questions

  validates_presence_of :email, :password, :first_name, :last_name, :user_group
  validates_uniqueness_of :email

  mount_uploader :small_cover, SmallCoverUploader

  before_create :generate_token
end

class SmallCoverUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
end
```

Schema:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20140619170102) do

  create_table "contracts", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "contractor_id"
    t.integer  "volunteer_id"
    t.boolean  "active"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.integer  "project_id"
    t.boolean  "dropped_out"
    t.boolean  "complete"
    t.boolean  "incomplete"
    t.boolean  "work_submitted"
  end

  create_table "conversations", force: true do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "volunteer_application_id"
    t.integer  "contract_id"
  end

  create_table "organizations", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "ruling_year"
    t.text     "mission_statement"
    t.string   "guidestar_membership"
    t.string   "ein"
    t.string   "street1"
    t.string   "street2"
    t.string   "city"
    t.integer  "state_id"
    t.string   "zip"
    t.integer  "ntee_major_category_id"
    t.string   "funding_method"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.string   "cause"
    t.string   "state_abbreviation"
    t.text     "goal"
    t.string   "contact_number"
    t.string   "contact_email"
    t.string   "budget"
  end

  create_table "private_messages", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "sender_id"
    t.integer  "recipient_id"
    t.string   "subject"
    t.text     "body"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.integer  "project_id"
    t.integer  "conversation_id"
  end

  create_table "projects", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.text     "description"
    t.string   "skills"
    t.string   "causes"
    t.datetime "deadline"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "organization_id"
    t.integer  "estimated_hours"
    t.string   "state"
  end

  create_table "questions", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.string   "title"
    t.text     "description"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "users", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "organization_id"
    t.string   "first_name"
    t.string   "last_name"
    t.string   "email"
    t.string   "interests"
    t.string   "skills"
    t.string   "street1"
    t.string   "street2"
    t.string   "city"
    t.integer  "state_id"
    t.integer  "phone_number"
    t.string   "zip"
    t.boolean  "organization_administrator"
    t.boolean  "organization_staff"
    t.boolean  "volunteer"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "password_digest"
    t.string   "position"
    t.integer  "project_id"
    t.string   "time_zone"
    t.text     "bio"
    t.string   "contact_reason"
    t.string   "organization_role"
    t.boolean  "nonprofit"
    t.string   "type"
    t.string   "user_group"
    t.string   "state_abbreviation"
    t.string   "new_password_token"
    t.integer  "profile_progress_status"
    t.string   "small_cover"
  end

  create_table "volunteer_applications", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "project_id"
    t.boolean  "accepted"
    t.boolean  "rejected"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.integer  "applicant_id"
    t.integer  "administrator_id"
  end

end
```

Uploader

```
class SmallCoverUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just want to make an update here, and I am happy to clarify if my brief answer does not satisfy the reader's curiosity.

I basically just used [cloudinary](http://cloudinary.com/) and [attachinary](https://github.com/assembler/attachinary).  This combo works like a dream. Goodbye Carrierwave!

Answer (score 0):

You should try separately with something like:

```
@user.small_cover.update(cover_params)
```

I guess your association is `belongs_to :small_cover`

You'll need to user a second strong parameter method (here called `cover_params`). That means you'll need to adapt `params`.

Comment: small_cover is the attribute that takes a string for the uploaded file name. I update the post to provide some more information

Comment: Then was is your CarrierWave implemented model ? Could you show us your User model with schema.rb and the uploader ?